# Profile loaded even after reboot

Tags: windows, profile

I manage an AVD machine and multiple users are logging in everyday.

The question I have is why accounts stay loaded even after reboot.

Here a screenshot of the accounts profiles

[List users (Yellow have not logged today)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feh75.png)

Anyone know how to force the unload of profile. Two of them have been in leave of absence since february and are still loaded on boot. Makes no sense.

We force reboot the computer every day at midnight.

Thanks

Comment: What is an AVD system? What sort of restart are you actually doing and how is it being triggered? Do the profiles load again if you power the machine down, disconnect power, and let it sit for a minute before powering it back on (as in, a TRUE power off situation)?

Comment: If you're talking about Azure Virtual Desktops, first, please use that full name at least once in your question so we know what you're talking about. Second, are these sessions running in Azure? What makes you believe they should be unloaded because you're restarting a computer (this might indicate I don't know much about the system)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, AVD is indeed Azure Virtual Desktop. And the sessions are supposed to be removed after logoff. they are not always done so. When I login on my sessions i see my session in the list and when I log off it is removed.